# Show/Hide div in DataList with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datalist

and I made a project with asp, but something is not working...I am trying to show/hide div which is inside of Datalist. But unfortunately is working only in first element, and the others element the div that I want to hide is appear.

here is my code:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#hiden").hide();
        $("#showddiv").on("click", function () {
            $("#hiden").toggle();
        });
    });

</script>
<div id="mainReferences">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333">
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#2E2E2E" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#151515" />
        <ItemTemplate>

           <table cellspacing="20">
           <tr>
           <td><a href="#" id="showddiv" class="fontText"  title="drop the div down"><img src='<%# Eval("Mainfoto") %>'  width="320px" height="290px" /> </a></td>
           <td width="400px"> 
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="FontText" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Përshkrimi:"></asp:Label><br />
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" width="400px" class="FontText" Font-Size="Large" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pershkrimi") %>' ></asp:Label></td>
           </tr>
           </table>


            <div id="hiden" class="categorry">             </div>  
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DataList>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-using `id` values in your HTML.  This is invalid markup and will likely lead to undefined behavior (probably different by browser as well).  Notice this element:

```
<div id="hiden" class="categorry">
```

Since this is essentially inside a loop (repeater, datalist, etc.) it's going to render multiple times to the page.  Instead of an `id`, use a `class`:

```
<div class="hiden categorry">
```

Then just change your jQuery selector:

```
$('.hiden')
```

Of course, now you also need to specifically identify *which* element you want to toggle.  You can do this by traversing the DOM a little bit from the clicked element.  Something like this:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.hiden').toggle();
```

This is an example, since I don't know the rendered markup resulting from your server-side code.  Essentially the selector in `.closest()` should refer to whatever parent element wraps that particular datalist item in the markup.  This basically looks for:  The element which was clicked -> a common parent between it and the element you want to toggle -> the element you want to toggle.

(Naturally, this same fix will need to be applied anywhere else you're duplicating `id` values, which you do a couple of times in your code.)

`id`s have to be unique in the DOM.  `class`es can be re-used.

Comment: But this answer is also not applicable by the way. It will display hidden divs from all the items of the datalist.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli: Good catch.  I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hiden").hide();

    $("#showddiv").on("click", function () {
        $("#hiden").toggle();
    });
});
```

You should try this.

Update:

Should be something like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <table cellspacing="20">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="showddiv" class="fontText"  title="drop the div down"><img src='<%# Eval("Mainfoto") %>'  width="320px" height="290px" /> </a>
            </td>
            <td width="400px"> 
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="FontText" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Përshkrimi:"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" width="400px" class="FontText" Font-Size="Large" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pershkrimi") %>' ></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="hiden" class="categorry">
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".categorry").hide();

    $(".showddiv").on("click", function () {
        $(this).closest('table').parent().find(".categorry").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no difference in both. i am just asking to try it this way, caz i don't see any other issue in the code. @David

Comment: Sorry the ids hidden is repeating. thats the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for these comments, it really helped me.  I would like to know also something else... When I click someone to open the div, it's jump me to the top of the page, so what to do to stay in that position that is opening?

Thank you again

Comment: @Hariss: This is because of the `href="#"`, which tells the browser to go to the top of the page.  Ideally you shouldn't be using a "link" for this, since you're not actually linking to anything.  It would be better to use something like a button and just style it to look like a link.  In a pinch, you *could* use `href="javascript:void(0);"` but that's not good practice.